# VS2015 Crashes when I try to Publish

Tags: azure, crash, visual-studio-2015

So, I am developing a Web Service, and at some point, my Visual Studio 2015 started to crash every time i right click project -> Publish. When I publish a project it gets deployed to Azure.

I use git, so I undid all the changes to my last successful project publish, and yes, I did publish after that build before.

I tried to remove/re-install Visual Studio, and nothing worked.

Last thing I did was reset Windows 10 to factory settings and install everything again. This still does not do anything.

Last thing I could do is Wipe my computer completely and install everything again, but I don't really want to resort to that!

I am desperate with this! I have resharper 9.2 installed and Xamarin.

Thank you,

Comment: Have you tried installing the latest Azure SDK?

Comment: Hello @CSharpRocks, yes I did. As soon as I press the publish button, vs stops responding, crashes and restarts.

Comment: @Mike Please consider marking [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33792171/75500) as the correct answer, it's a simpler solution and has double the votes.

Comment: Even though that solution did not solve my problem, I'll mark it as requested.

Comment: still I have this problem and nothing helps from the suggested answers...

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The closest thing I've found to solving it is to right-click the project and select 'Clean' before then selecting 'Publish'.

Answer (score 10):

Apparently I fixed this by:

right clicking project-> properties -> Package/Publish SQL -> Import from Web.config

It seems that somehow the project lost some properties regarding these settings, even though they were in the web.config.

Comment: Dude, you are a freaking genius!!! Thanks a lot, I was having this problem with both: Visual Studio 2013 and 2015!!! My problem started after I installed Azure SDK on VS 2015... Anyways, it is solved now :D :D

Comment: Glad I could help! @JoseA

Comment: This worked for me, enough though I don't publish a db. I just deselected it after a web.config import. Thank you, so much

Comment: Thank you so much this was driving me crazy!

Answer (score 7):

I faced same issue with VS 2015 Community Edition while publish.
Just installed latest Azure SDK for .Net (VS 2015) - 2.8.1(Or latest one) and it solved the problem.

Comment: OP already says he installed the latest version and that this didn't solve his problem

Comment: I'll confirm as well that installing latest Azure SDK 2.8.1 fixed the issue for me. Before I tried this, the Clean and Publish method was all I could do. To note: I never had the Azure SDK installed so it wasn't an update for me but a full install that created new features inside of VS. I suspect it overwrites or changes certain core publish or Microsoft.BCL build libs in some way that are not easy to pinpoint otherwise. I can say with certainty that this wasn't an issue between VS2013 vs VS2015, both had the identical problem and were solved with the Azure SDK install. Hope this helps someone

Comment: also want to add, this issue only showed up after I installed the Win 10 Service Pack 1 ( i know they don't call it that ) .            Further, after the Win 10.1 update, I also lost the ability to use MVC4 scaffolding for creating new controllers.I feel it might be an important clue for others that are not getting a resolve yet.

Comment: @BillD, I should add my experience again for this issue that If I do not install latest Azure SDK, VS2015 crashes even I clean the project before publish. And Installing Azure SDK is also not a complete solution, I always have to clean the solution before publish. One month passed and I have been doing clean before publish every time. VS team must fix this bug.

Answer (score 1):

hit this problem myself, i found that deleting the publish profiles worked.
Expand the properties container under the project that keeps crashing and delete PublishProfiles.

> warning: you will have to recreate the publish profiles you have just
>   deleted.

Answer (score 1):

Deleting the ***.suo** file in **v14** folder helped in my case.

Cleaning the solution occasionally worked, but 90% of time the VS crashed anyways.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I updated Azure SDK first and then opened solution then right-click the project and select 'Clean'. Then clicked on publish and now i imported the publish profile or created custom profiles, no issue.

Comment: I don't understand how this is different from Mike's answer.

Comment: Indeed Mike's step helped me. But I had to update Azure SDK before Mike's steps.

Answer (score 0):

I have been having this issue as well. What worked for me was logging into Azure through Visual Studio, making sure I was connected in the Server Explorer, and then trying to publish afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

For those who still couldn't make it work, Make sure you `publish in "Release"` mode. For me I was trying to publish in Debug mode which hangs the publish window.