# VS2015 when trying to Validate Connection crashes Faulting module name: clr.dll, version: 4.6.1063.1

Tags: windows, visual-studio, clr, windows-10, publishing

I am using `VS2015` and trying to validate connection after importing publish profile generated by winhost, when I click on `Validate connection` VS2015 crashes.

I have tried [cleaning up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32868648/vs2015-crashes-when-i-try-to-publish) and rebuilding but hat didn't help, I have also restarted machine without any luck.

[image]

[image]

I have also enabled logging by running `devenv /Log` but can't make any sense out of `ActivityLog.xml` what went wrong exactly, I [have uploaded it here](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=66305103292204059587)

**What went wrong with Visual Studio 2015 and how could I fix it?**

**UPDATE:** I also tried resetting settings `devenv /resetsettings` but that didn't help.

EventLog shows following Error:

```
Faulting application name: devenv.exe, version: 14.0.24720.0, time stamp: 0x564ea97e
Faulting module name: clr.dll, version: 4.6.1063.1, time stamp: 0x5653653c
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x0007482d
Faulting process ID: 0x13f0
Faulting application start time: 0x01d17609c3c2b002
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Report ID: 2fab7a5b-6003-417f-adb3-8f45ec987a72
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

**Update2:**

As per @magicandre1981 request. I ran `procdump -ma -i C:\dumps` from command line before doing anything else. Then ran `VS2015`, went to `publish` and clicked on `Test connection` when VS crashed, there was a .dmp file in `C:\dumps`. [Here's zipped dump file](https://db.tt/s83HjbW2)

Comment: Well, that is not supposed to happen, you need to get your machine healthy again.  What happened to it is an important detail that, oddly, is never included in the question.  Most common reason is buggy anti-malware or firewall, the kind of crapware that gets involved in networking, so start there first.

Comment: @HansPassant Hi Hans, no antimalware just normal Windows 10 firewall, didn't install any crapware machine is very clean it that sense. I did recently install Xamarin and did some development with Android Studio alongside VS2015 could this be the cause? How could I debug this further? What indicates that this is networking?

Comment: Well, you can debug it by using a debugger.  Start VS again and use Debug > Attach to Process.  Select devenv.exe, use the native debugging engine.  Debug > Windows > Exception settings to force it to stop.  Interpreting the call stack to diagnose the cause is a bit, well.  At least you can document your question better.

Comment: @HansPassant Heh, It crashed when I clicked `Attach to process`, I guess it's going to be Windows reinstall. Thanks Hans.

Comment: look in eventlog for source **.net** with EventID 1026 entries. It should show you the .net callstack. if this doesn't help, create a dmp with WER (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513638(VS.85).aspx) or Procdump (procdump -ma -i C:\dumps) and analyze it with Windbg

Comment: @magicandre1981 have only one of those `Application: iisexpress.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: exception code c0000008, exception address A252897A
` happened on 08/01/2016 so I believe it is unlikely that it's related, but thanks anyway. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: capture a dmp, zip the dmp and share the dmp (onedrive)

Comment: @magicandre1981 Hi Andre, I thought dmp files are captured on system crashes (I don't get BSOD only VS2015 crashes and closes itself) do I need to set up windows 10 somehow specifically to capture application crashes too. Reason I am asking is I when I paste in to explorer bar `%SystemRoot%\MEMORY.DMP`, it cannot find the file I have checked in startup settings and dmp seems to be enabled http://snag.gy/fAUV3.jpg . I must be missing something here. Thanks.

Comment: I don't talk about memory.dmp, I talk about usermode application crash dump. Use Procdump or the WER setting to create a crash dump of VS.

Comment: @magicandre1981 Hi Andre, so I fired up VS then went into `task manager` clicked on the visual studio and then `create dump file`  then went into VS and clicked to Test connection like descripbed in steps above here's zipped dump file https://db.tt/s83HjbW2 Thanks.

Comment: this dump is useless (64 bit dnp of 32bit application). Apply the registry setting to configure WER to generate dumps or run the procdump command that I posted to configure procdump as post Mortem debugger to generate proper dumps

Comment: @magicandre1981 Hi Andre, I appreciate your help, have a look at this https://db.tt/s83HjbW2 I hope I did it right this time, I am not very good with dump files. What I did I ran visual studio and did publish and when i crashed I ran `procdump devenv`. Thanks.

Comment: Rrun **procdump -ma -i C:\dumps** BEFORE doing anything else. Now run VS, do the action and when VS crashes, you see a dmp in **C:\dumps**.

Comment: @magicandre1981 https://db.tt/s83HjbW2 done.

Comment: ok, this time you did everything correct, but Microsoft made a mistake. They forgot to upload a debug file (PDB) for the 32Bit ntdll.dll on their symbol server. I reported it to Microsoft and when they upload the PDB I'll look at the dmp again.

Comment: @magicandre1981 Thanks Andre, you're a star!

Comment: ok, Microsoft is aware of the PDB issue and they investigate it now.

Comment: ok, the PDB is now online. The crash (NULL_POINTER_READ_INVALID_POINTER_READ) happens at **clr!MethodTableBuilder::CreateMethodChainHash+0x8a** (function to Create a hash of all methods in this class).  I have no idea how to fix it. Submit the issue to Microsoft via connect: connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/

Comment: @magicandre1981 thanks Andre.

Comment: @magicandre1981 Hi Andre, Could you post last comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, the PDB is now online and I was able to look at the dzmp with Windbg. The crash (`NULL_POINTER_READ_INVALID_POINTER_READ`) happens at `clr!MethodTableBuilder::CreateMethodChainHash+0x8a`.

I have no idea how to fix it. Submit the issue to [Microsoft via connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/) so that Microsoft can fix it with the Update 3.